# Как удалить системные уведомления Telegram? delete_message

Tags: python, telegram

Нужно удалить системные уведомления, кто вступил в группу и кто вышел с группы,много информации прочитал, но не получается, самое главное чтобы код был на библиотеке telebot, или на другой библиотеке, чтобы дружили между собой,так как хочу чтобы все было в одном файле.

Я делал по разном, но в группе не удаляется, кто вступил или вышел с группы.

```python
import time
from telebot import TeleBot, types

bot = TeleBot('moy_token')



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message_handler(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def my_event_handler(event): 
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def deleted (message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите,как решить проблему в данном вопросе, а так же, может еще какие то библиотеки, нужно установить и прописать в файле.
Есть код на библиотеке telethon и он отлично работает, но так как я хочу чтобы и ссылки удалялись, но telethon и telebot не дружать и выкидывает ошибку.
Вот код:

```python3
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
api_id = ***
api_hash = '***'
bot_token = '***'

client = TelegramClient('my_account', api_id, api_hash)
bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
```

Надо чтобы они подружились, или какое то другое решение.

Comment: Я ничего не менял, только дописал нижний код.

Comment: У бота есть права админа?

Comment: Да права админа есть.

Comment: Извините, наверное недоглядел как нужно вставлять код, это моя не внимательность.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=util.content_type_service)
def delall(message: types.Message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id,message.message_id)
```

[pyTelegramBotAPI.examples](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/1688a466f44e9a2dccf2fb7aee6ad71b222982fc/examples/chat_member_example.py#L30)